# ExpandableListView works remembers checked itme and do the same to other child layout

Tags: android, checkbox, expandablelistview

I use `ExpandableListView`. There I have `checkBox` (in `child_layout`) and when i checked one of them and close this `parent_layout` and then open other `parent_layout` there is also checked (automatically) the checkBox.

[I opened Sports and then checked Football (child) and then closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILuPm.jpg)

[And when I opened the second one (Sciences) the `checkBox` was automatically checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2yy6.jpg)

And how can I manage it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your adapter.
For example,you can save a boolean const to save each item's check status.And judge it in getView().Set the checkkbox status checking when the boolean is true.

Comment: Can you write it more concretely ?